How to navigate back to a specific screen in Flutter using named routes?
I'm building a Flutter app with multiple screens, and I'm using named routes for navigation. I want to navigate back to a specific screen in the route stack, not just the previous screen.
For example, I have a home screen (/home), a cart screen (/cart), and a orders screen (/orders). From the orders screen, I want to navigate back directly to the home screen, skipping the cart screen. How can I achieve this using named routes in Flutter?

To navigate back to a specific screen using named routes in Flutter, you can use the Navigator's "popUntil" method. This method allows you to pop the route stack until a specific condition is met. In your case, you can use it to pop all routes until you reach the home screen.
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));

You can also read more about it in official docs here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html

I believe you can use
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/home'));


You can navigate to the desired screen by just providing it's name (in Named Routes):

To just navigate to home screen (add it to route stack):
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Home");


To navigate to home screen but (replace the current screen with it)
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("Home");


To navigate to home and remove all routes in the stack
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("Home", (route) => false);



it's supposed you have the routes names predefined or handled by onGenerateRoute method
